# How can I order elements in this case? - Django

Tags: python, django, django-models

So I have a list of models,
don't think the structure of these models is important.
In this case Articles.

---

So these Articles are ordered by popularity between a rank of 1 to 100, all the other articles have no ranks.

Whenever I update the rank of a model the model with equivalent rank must loose its rank.

---

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean something like this?

```
def update_rank(rank, article):
      old = Article.object.get(rank=rank)
      old.rank = None
      old.save()
      article.rank = rank
      article.save()
```

Comment: Shouldn't the rank of the old one (and all the others below it) move down one, and the 100th item loose it's rank?